# Keras Model Not Being Created

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am copying a code from the Keras Documentation:

```
img_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
dense = Dense(64, activation="relu")
x = dense(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = Dense(10)(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="mnist_model")
model.summary()
```

But, the model summary is as follows:

```
______________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Expected** Model Summary:

```
Model: "mnist_model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 784)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                50240     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 55,050
Trainable params: 55,050
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.tensordot_11), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_6/kernel:0' shape=(50, 64) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.nn.bias_add_24), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_6/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.tensordot_12), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_7/kernel:0' shape=(64, 64) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.nn.bias_add_25), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_7/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.tensordot_13), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_8/kernel:0' shape=(64, 10) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (tf.nn.bias_add_26), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'dense_8/bias:0' shape=(10,) dtype=float32>
It is possible that this is intended behavior, but it is more likely
an omission. This is a strong indication that this layer should be
formulated as a subclassed Layer rather than a Lambda layer.
Model: "mnist_model"
```

I can't figure out what is causing the issue. I have implemented the same code earlier and I didn't face this issue then. I am currently using TensorFlow 2.5.

**Edit 1:** Documentation Link- https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/

**Edit 2:** Imports

```
# !pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv3D, MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling3D, Softmax, Multiply, Dense, concatenate, Dropout, Flatten, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.activations import softmax
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, History
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Edit 3:** Reproducible Example

```
# !pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.5.0
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv3D, MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling3D, Softmax, Multiply, Dense, concatenate, Dropout, Flatten, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.activations import softmax
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, History
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inputs = tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
dense = Dense(64, activation="relu")
x = dense(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = Dense(10)(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="mnist_model")
model.summary()
```

Comment: You should add a self-contained reproducible example, including all imports.

Comment: I have added the imports. Not quite sure what you mean by self-contained reproducible example. Can you tell me more ?

Comment: An example that we can run. Look at your imports, you are mixing use of keras and tf.keras, these are not the same library and are incompatible.

Comment: Yeah, I did some reading, I commented out the keras parts and restarted the kernel only with the tensorflow imports active. The result is still the same.

Comment: Your "Reproducible Example" is not Reproducible! you have a variable "inputs" that has never been defined.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy You were right, it was the mixup of keras and tf. The error was with 'inputs'. Thanks for pointing out the error, made the change!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 3D input to the Dense layer without flattening it. I think this causes the warning.
However for getting the expected model summary,
first `import tensorflow` and change the input layer to `inputs = tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(784,))`

Here is the full snippet of the code.

```
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv3D, MaxPooling2D, MaxPooling3D, Softmax, Multiply, Dense, concatenate, Dropout, Flatten, LSTM, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.activations import softmax
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, History
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

inputs = tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(784,))
dense = Dense(64, activation="relu")
x = dense(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = Dense(10)(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="mnist_model")
model.summary()
```